# Common base class initialization

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

Take the scenario

BaseA -> SubB -> SubSubC

Explanation: SubSubC class inherits SubB class. The SubB class inherits BaseA class

BaseA -> SubD -> SubSubE

Explanation: SubSubE class inherits SubD class. The SubB class inherits BaseA class

So..on..

So there are many class that has its grand parent class as BaseA . The BaseA class has some properties that are common to all the methods. ex: CustomerID, LastLogin, UniqueName etc.

This is how the class is designed in the service which I'm consuming.

My doubt is While calling the service methods, all the methods would expect a parameter of any SubSub class. Can anyone please tell me, is there any way if I could assign values to the properties of the BaseA in one place so that while creating the SubSub objects I did not need to fill the base properties each time?

I'm using C# as my language.

Code:

```
public class BaseA
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string UniqueName { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubB : BaseA
    {
    }
    public class SubSubC : SubB
    {

    }

    public class SubD : BaseA
    {
    }
    public class SubSubE : SubD
    {

    }

    public class MyMain
    {
        public void SendRequestToService1()
        {
            (new MyServiceObject()).ServiceMethod1(new SubSubC());
        }

        public void SendRequestToService2()
        {
            (new MyServiceObject()).ServiceMethod2(new SubSubE());
        }
    }
```

In the above code, in SendRequestToService1 and SendRequestToService2 , i need to initialise the base class properties CustomerId and UniqueName.
Ex:

```
(new SubSubC(){ CustomerId=2, UniqueName="XXBB" });
```

If there are many methods, I need to initialize these properties each time for their respective classes. Is there a way I can initialize the base properties CustomerId and UniqueName in one place so that the inheriting classes(SubSubC,SubSubE here) no need to initialize when their objects are created?

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Looks like "I want to initialize properties of instances of class `BaseA` in one function, can I write it?"... sample code that demostrates problem you are facing would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the following functionality?

```
    //dummy class replacing the service object and it's methods
    public class MyServiceObject
    {
        public void ServiceMethod1(SubSubC param)
        { }
        public void ServiceMethod2(SubSubE param)
        { }
    }

    public class BaseA
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string UniqueName { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubB : BaseA
    {
    }
    public class SubSubC : SubB
    {
    }

    public class SubD : BaseA
    {
    }
    public class SubSubE : SubD
    {
    }

    public class MyMain
    {
        //declare the SubSub objects
        //SubSubC subSubC;
        //SubSubE subSubE;
        BaseA baseA;

        public MyMain()
        {
            //assign the values to each class in the MyMain contrsuctor
            baseA = new BaseA { CustomerId = 2, UniqueName = "XXBB" };

        }

        public void SendRequestToService1()
        {
            var subSub=new SubSubC();
            (new MyServiceObject()).ServiceMethod1(Initialize(subSub));
        }

        public void SendRequestToService2()
        {
            var subSub = new SubSubE();
            (new MyServiceObject()).ServiceMethod2(Initialize(subSub));
        }

        private T Initialize<T>(T subSub) where T:BaseA
        {
            subSub.CustomerId = baseA.CustomerId;
            subSub.UniqueName = baseA.UniqueName;
            return subSub;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyMain myMain = new MyMain();
            myMain.SendRequestToService1();
            myMain.SendRequestToService2();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You got the point, but you are assigning the CustomerId,UniquName multiple times in the MyMain constructor.In my case the CustomerId and UniqueName is going to be same(may be from Session) for both SubSubC & SubSubE. In this case can you let me know instead of assigning the CustomerId & UniqueName properties eachtime when i create the subsubC,subsubE etc objects , can i do it in one place so i dont need to assign it again and again while creating the objects.

Comment: Yes its good. But please note that as mentioned in my questions these are the classes that are defined in the service which i am consuming. So i don't have options to change it.

Comment: And how about this resolution? `private T Initialize<T>(ref T subSub) where T:BaseA` should do the magic.

Comment: You do not need the `ref` keyword here, especially since you're returning the object being initialized.  But even if the method were a void method, you would not need the ref keyword.  Also, you do not need the type parameter in the suggestion made in your last comment if you make it a void method.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about calling base constructors?  If so:

```
class SubSubC : SubB
{
    public object CProperty { get; private set; }
    public SubSubC(object cProperty, string bProperty, int id) : base(bProperty, id)
    {
        CProperty = cProperty;
    }
}
class SubB : BaseA
{
    public string BProperty { get; private set; }
    public SubB(string bProperty, int id) : base(id)
    {
        BProperty = bProperty;
    }
}
class BaseA
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    public BaseA(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
}
```

Or are you asking about initializing objects in a method?  If so (assume the setters are public in the following code, unlike in the preceding):

```
void SetSubSubCProperties(SubSubC c, object cProperty, string bProperty, int id)
{
    c.CProperty = cProperty;
    SetSubBProperties(c, bProperty, id);
}
void SetSubBProperties(SubB b, string bProperty, int id)
{
    b.BProperty = bProperty;
    SetBaseAProperties(b, id);
}
void SetBaseAProperties(BaseA a, int id)
{
    a.ID = id;
}
```

Ok, Alex Filipovici's answer, it looks like you want to initialize an instance of a derived class by copying the base class properties from an instance of a *different* derived class.  In that case, to reduce the duplication in Alex's answer, you can do this:

```
void Initialize(BaseA source, BaseA target)
{
    target.CustomerID = source.CustomerID;
    target.UniqueName = source.UniqueName;
}
```

Then, to modify his example:

```
public void SendRequestToService1()
{
    var subSub = new SubSubC();
    Initialize(this.baseA, subSub);
    (new MyServiceObject()).ServiceMethod1(subSub);
}

public void SendRequestToService2()
{
    var subSub = new SubSubE();
    Initialize(this.baseA, subSub);
    (new MyServiceObject()).ServiceMethod2(subSub);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is for initializing the base class properties within the inherited classes.I have these classes in the service and I want to initialize the base properties(in a common place) before I send the Child class as a parameter to the service.

Comment: @clklachu so ... is the answer adequate, or is it somehow missing your point?

Comment: I feel there could be better answer that could suit my scenario.

Comment: @clklachu I would be able to do a better job of improving my answer if you could explain what's inadequate about it.  I have added a modification of Alex Filipovici's answer which removes some of the redundant complications he introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question.

```
public class A {
  public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class B : A {
}
```

you can do `B b = new B()` and then `b.ID = 12`.

---

Or, if you have a method that gets a parameter of type `A` in your service you can change the value in the same way.

```
public void doSomething(A a) {
  a.ID = 12;
}
```

and call the method with instances of `B` - `doSomething(new B())`